# I am looking for a way to set noindex tags on all the string filters parameters

Tags: url, php, noindex, url-parameters

I don't want to use robots.txt for this. Any PHP code or any .http access lines will work like a charm. Now I show you what types of urls I want to eradicate.

https://www.example.com/search-gadgets/?filters=ram.3-gb

Here is a robots.txt code I'm using to block such urls.

```
Disallow: /*sort=
Disallow: /*filters=
```

But the thing is Robots.txt doesn't implement Noindex tags, as it just blocks the urls from being crawled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **htaccess**, you can use the http header `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` to accomplish what you need for the specific files you need, or with a pattern.

You can also provide other instructions, such as noarchive, nofollow, or even be specific for a particular crawler, for example Googlebot:

```
X-Robots-Tag: googlebot: nofollow
X-Robots-Tag: otherbot: noindex, nofollow
```

Source:
https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag